# Enable custom callbacks for Handlebars helpers

Tags: javascript, callback, handlebars.js

I'm providing API that wraps Handlebars and also implements some helper methods out of the box. I would like to allow consumers of these helper methods to provide their custom implementation if needed by providing them callbacks to implement.

For that, I provided the following method:

```
function extendHelper(methodName, callback){
    customHelpers[methodName] = callback;
}
```

Here is an example how to use it:

```
extendHelper("someHelperMethod", function(param, result) {
    if (param=="width"){
        return parseInt(result,10) + 1;
    } else {
        return result;
    }
});
```

Any suggestions of doing it in more elegant way?

Comment: Can you clarify the main idea? For what purposes you trying to **extend** helpers, when helpers can be simply **redefined** without using any wrappers?

Comment: Internally, the helpers I'm providing are using some mapping json files and some logic to get the value to render. For most cases, the helpers would be sufficient but there are some cases where I would like consumers to modify the result.

The templates actually transform some type of UI technology to another UI technology. Let's  say that for a width of control, in most cases the conversion is 1:1 and the out of the box helpers can be used. When it's not the case someone would want to change the width based on his logic and calculations.

Comment: That's make sense, thanks! I'll think how you can implement it in more elegant way with Handlebars.